# Using iOS charts library, get value from line chart when there is more than one line in the chart

Tags: ios, swift, ios-charts

```
func updatePenValue() {
    if let highlight = chartView.getHighlightByTouchPoint(scrollerView.center) {
        penValueLabel.text = Double.getPenValueInString(value: highlight.y)
        dateTimeLabel.text = Date.get24HourDateString(date:
            Date.getDateFromInterval(timeInterval: highlight.x))
    }
}
```

In the above code snippet I,m getting the highlight by touch point is there something I can do to get all the lines value in the graph please suggest me? 
Actually I want the value of the chart at that particular point for one line it's working but for more than one line sometime it's returning line1's data and sometime line2's data what I want is both of line's data is there any thing that I can do to get values of all the lines??
GitHub page - https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts

Comment: Are you referring to this library ? https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts if yes please add it to the description.

Comment: yes.. @Mosbah this one https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts

Comment: What you want is show all points data on charts right ?

Comment: Actually I want the value of the chart at that particular point for one line it's working but for more than one line sometime it's returning line1's data and sometime line2's data what I want is both of line's data is there any thing that I can do to get values of all the lines?? @CodeChanger

Comment: so means that if line1 and line2 have same value at some point and if you click on that point you need both value data right ?

Comment: You should have your data model, which you plot your graph from. Once you get one point, you can take the x coordinate and get the points of the other lines from your original model.

Comment: No line1 and line2 may have any value at some point but I need both the values.@CodeChanger

Comment: @RickyMo actually I,m showing breaks in the graph so it's difficult to keep track of all the data sets. That's why I'm asking that is there any other thing I can do so that I will get all the line's point value at that corresponding pixel??

Answer (score 1):

Not really sure what your trying to achieve but Ill give you a few options to hopefully achieve what your after.

First you can get the DataSet of the line highlighted. You do this like so

```
let dataSet = chartView?.data?.dataSets[ highlight.dataSetIndex]
```

This then returns the data set label name and all data points that will look something like this

```
Optional(Charts.LineChartDataSet, label: Some Title, 4 entries:
ChartDataEntry, x: 1.0, y 216.0
ChartDataEntry, x: 2.0, y 243.0
ChartDataEntry, x: 3.0, y 310.0
ChartDataEntry, x: 4.0, y 461.0)
```

You can then use `map` to get just the data you need

```
let title = dataSet.map({ $0.label })
```

There are also other options like

```
let itemAtXValue = dataSet.map({ $0.entriesForXValue(3.0) }
```

This will return the value of the selected line at 3.0 of the x axis.

Let me know how you get on.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and the solution but I already got one by thinking about it a little bit.